# Spring batch remote chunking - returning data from slave node

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using spring batch remote chunking for distributed processing.
When a slave node is done with processing a chunk I would like to return some additional data along with `ChunkResponse`.
For example if a chunk consist of 10 user Ids I would like to return in response how many user ids were processed successfully.
The response could include some other data as well. 
I have spent considerable time trying to figure out ways to achieve this
but without any success. 
For example I have tried to extend `ChunkResponse` class and add some additional fields to it. And then extend `ChunkProcessorChunkHandler`
and return customized `ChunkResponse` from it. But I am not sure if this is proper approach.

I also need a way on master node to read the `ChunkResponse` in some callback. I guess I can use `afterChunk(ChunkContext)` method of `ChunkListener`
but I couldn't find a way to get `ChunkResponse` from `ChunkContext` in the method.

So to sump it up I would like to know how can I pass data from slave to master per chunk and on master node how can I read this data.

Thanks a lot.

> EDIT

In my case master node reads user records and slave nodes process these records. At the end of the job
master needs to take conditional action based on whether processing of a particular user failed or succeeded. The fail/success on 
slave node is not based on any exception thrown there but based on some business rules. And there is other data that master needs to know about, for example 
how many emails were sent for each user. Now if I was using remote partitioning I could use `jobContext` to put and get this data but in remote chunking
`jobContext` is not available. So I was wondering if along with `ChunkResponse` I could send back some additional data from slave to master.

Comment: Can you describe your use case?  Remote chunking isn't intended to provide any additional functionality that Spring Batch would provide in a normal step which is what this sounds like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Michael. I have updated the post to describe my use case.